# Functions to deal with Unicode string manipulation with PowerBuilder 12.1

Tags: unicode, powerbuilder

I am currently working on converting our PowerBuilder 12.1 application, which does not currently support Unicode, into a Unicode supporting application.

I have made some modifications to save Unicode data to our database, as well to files, but I have hit a slight snag in processing strings.

For example, the character  is a Surrogate Pair and PowerBuilder interprets this as 2 characters (similar to how .NET operates). Thus:

```
LEN("") = 2
```

To me, this part makes sense, as it is count each code unit as a character.

Currently we have come up with two solutions to handle doing string functions with Unicode characters:

- Callable OLEObjects written in C# .NET
- using the PBNI interface to call C# .NET (**want to stay away from this solution if possible**)

An example of the .NET code we are thinking of using for determining the string length is:

```
StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters("").Length = 1
```

We are just worried about the impact on performance with constantly calling the OLEObjects/PBNI to do all of our string processing. Have any of the other PowerBuilder developers here done Unicode string manipulation (LEN, MID, POS, etc), and how did you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the release 10, PB is unicode (utf-16le)-aware. So the legacy `Len()` is implicit `LenW()` (as other string functions, and dealing with legacy data could imply to use explicit `LenA()`).

Are you sure that you are getting some utf-16le encoding ? Given the following function, what does it return on a string containing your data, if you call it with `hexdump_blob(blob(your_string))`?

Paste this code into the source code of a new global function named `hexdump_blob` to have an hexadecimal display  (hex editor like) for blob contents.

```
global type hexdump_blob from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function string hexdump_blob (blob abl_data, boolean ab_fill_lastline)
end prototypes

global function string hexdump_blob (blob abl_data, boolean ab_fill_lastline);//hexify a blob content
string ls_tohex = "0123456789ABCDEF"
string ls_msg = "", ls_line, ls_binary
long i, j, length
byte b
string ls_fill

if isnull( abl_data ) then return ""

if ab_fill_lastline then
    ls_fill = " __"
else
    ls_fill = "   "
end if

length = len( abl_data )
for i = 1 to length
    GetByte( abl_data, i, b )
    ls_line += mid( ls_tohex, 1+ mod(int(b/16),16), 1)
    ls_line += mid( ls_tohex, 1+ mod(b,16), 1)
    ls_line += " "
    ls_binary += string( iif(b>31 and b<128,char(b)," "))
    if mod(i,16) = 0 and i > 0 then
        ls_binary = replaceall( ls_binary, "~r", "·")   //no cr/lf
        ls_binary = replaceall( ls_binary, "~n", "·")
        ls_binary = replaceall( ls_binary, "~t", "·")
        ls_msg += "[" + string( i - 16, "0000") + "] " + ls_line + "~t" + ls_binary + "~r~n"
        ls_line = ""
        ls_binary = ""
    end if
next
i -- // i - 1 due to the last loop in for
ls_line += fill(ls_fill, 3 * ( 16 - mod(i, 16) ) )
ls_msg += "[" + string( i - mod(i,16), "0000") + "] " + ls_line + "~t" + ls_binary

return ls_msg

end function
```

Also, here is the `replaceall()` function that is used by `hexdump_blob()`

```
global type replaceall from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function string replaceall (string as_source, string as_pattern, string as_replace)
end prototypes

global function string replaceall (string as_source, string as_pattern, string as_replace);//remplace toute les occurences de as_pattern de as_source par as_replace 
string ls_target
long i, j

ls_target=""
i = 1
j = 1
do
    i = pos( as_source, as_pattern, j )
    if i>0 then
        ls_target += mid( as_source, j, i - j )
        ls_target += as_replace
        j = i + len( as_pattern )
    else
        ls_target += mid( as_source, j )
    end if
loop while i>0

return ls_target
end function
```

and the `iif()` that simulates the C ternary operator, or the visual basic iif()

```
global type iif from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function any iif (boolean ab_cond, any aa_true, any aa_false)
end prototypes

global function any iif (boolean ab_cond, any aa_true, any aa_false);
// simulates the VB iif or C ternary operator

if ab_cond then
    return aa_true
else
    return aa_false
end if

end function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to Seki's hex conversion function. I'm posting it as an answer so I can include source code. I use the Microsoft cryptographic functions to display blobs in my debugging tools. Here's a simplified version of my blob window. The one I use is PFC-based and uses an object that wraps the MS Crypto library. It's from PB 12.5 but should import into any Unicode version of PB.

```
HA$PBExportHeader$w_show_blob.srw
forward
global type w_show_blob from window
end type
type sle_1 from singlelineedit within w_show_blob
end type
type mle_1 from multilineedit within w_show_blob
end type
end forward

global type w_show_blob from window
integer width = 3081
integer height = 1988
boolean titlebar = true
boolean controlmenu = true
boolean minbox = true
boolean maxbox = true
boolean resizable = true
boolean center = true
sle_1 sle_1
mle_1 mle_1
end type
global w_show_blob w_show_blob

type prototypes
FUNCTION boolean CryptBinaryToString ( &
    Blob pbBinary, &
    ulong cbBinary, &
    ulong dwFlags, &
    Ref string pszString, &
    Ref ulong pcchString ) &
LIBRARY "crypt32.dll" ALIAS FOR "CryptBinaryToStringW"

end prototypes

type variables
CONSTANT Ulong CRYPT_STRING_HEXASCIIADDR = 11   

end variables

forward prototypes
public subroutine of_showblob (ref blob abl_data)
end prototypes

public subroutine of_showblob (ref blob abl_data);unsignedlong lul_size, lul_bufsize
string ls_hex
try
    lul_size = len(abl_data)
    sle_1.text = string(lul_size)


    setnull(ls_hex)
    cryptbinarytostring( abl_data, lul_size, CRYPT_STRING_HEXASCIIADDR, ls_hex, lul_bufsize)
    ls_hex = space(lul_bufsize)
    if not cryptbinarytostring( abl_data, lul_size, CRYPT_STRING_HEXASCIIADDR , ls_hex, lul_bufsize) then
        mle_1.text = "error converting blob data"
    else
        mle_1.text = ls_hex
    end if
catch(runtimeerror re)
    messagebox("oops", re.text)


end try


end subroutine

on w_show_blob.create
this.sle_1=create sle_1
this.mle_1=create mle_1
this.Control[]={this.sle_1,&
this.mle_1}
end on

on w_show_blob.destroy
destroy(this.sle_1)
destroy(this.mle_1)
end on

type sle_1 from singlelineedit within w_show_blob
integer x = 73
integer width = 517
integer height = 88
integer taborder = 10
integer textsize = -10
integer weight = 400
fontcharset fontcharset = ansi!
fontpitch fontpitch = variable!
fontfamily fontfamily = swiss!
string facename = "Arial"
long textcolor = 33554432
long backcolor = 553648127
string text = "none"
boolean displayonly = true
borderstyle borderstyle = stylelowered!
end type

type mle_1 from multilineedit within w_show_blob
integer x = 64
integer y = 96
integer width = 2898
integer height = 1716
integer taborder = 10
integer textsize = -10
integer weight = 400
fontcharset fontcharset = ansi!
fontpitch fontpitch = fixed!
fontfamily fontfamily = modern!
string facename = "Courier New"
long textcolor = 33554432
string text = "none"
boolean hscrollbar = true
boolean vscrollbar = true
boolean displayonly = true
borderstyle borderstyle = stylelowered!
end type
```

To use it, assuming your blob is lbl_myBlob:

```
open(w_show_blob)
w_show_blob.of_showblob(lbl_myBlob)
```

The output in the MLE looks like this:

```
0000    42 4d ee 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 76 00 00 00 28 00   BM........v...(.
0010    00 00 10 00 00 00 0f 00  00 00 01 00 04 00 00 00   ................
0020    00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..x.............
0030    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 80 00 00 80   ................
0040    00 00 00 80 80 00 80 00  00 00 80 00 80 00 80 80   ................
0050    00 00 80 80 80 00 c0 c0  c0 00 00 00 ff 00 00 ff   ................
0060    00 00 00 ff ff 00 ff 00  00 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff ff   ................
0070    00 00 ff ff ff 00 88 88  88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88   ................
0080    80 88 88 88 88 88 88 88  80 08 88 88 88 88 88 88   ................
0090    80 00 88 88 88 88 88 88  80 00 08 88 88 88 88 88   ................
00a0    80 00 00 88 88 88 88 88  80 00 00 08 88 88 88 88   ................
00b0    80 00 00 00 88 88 88 88  80 00 00 08 88 88 88 88   ................
00c0    80 00 00 88 88 88 88 88  80 00 08 88 88 88 88 88   ................
00d0    80 00 88 88 88 88 88 88  80 08 88 88 88 88 88 88   ................
00e0    80 88 88 88 88 88 88 88  88 88 88 88 88 88         ..............
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to use the LenA() method?

http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/New_in_PowerBuilder_10/PB10New_-_Unicode_Support/PB10New_-_Unicode_Related_Chan/PB10New_-_String-Related_Funct/pb10new_-_modified_processing_.html

Comment: As `LenA()` is for ansi text, I guess that the OP won't have a different result.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately LenA() won't work for what we are looking for. We're trying to count by the total visual characters and not by code units.